# How to pass a td value to sql select query in html

Tags: html, sql, asp.net

I want to pass a value in td to a select query

For example

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="getdb" runat="server" Connection string Select command="Select*from [table] where id=TD"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I just don't know the syntax to pass the td value

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to fill that parameter "TD" you can do it two ways, either fill it right from the `SqlDataSource` or you can fill it from Codebehind which seem to me that would be the better way for your problem.

Asp.net code:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [your table] WHERE id = @TD">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="yourLabelID" PropertyName="Text" Name="TD"></asp:ControlParameter>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Fill this SqlDataSource with your needed data like the ControlID of the desired Control with the needed data which will fill the Parameter in the SELECT.

If you want to fill it from Codebind use the following code:

Asp.net code for SqlDataSource:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [your table] WHERE id = @TD">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="TD"></asp:Parameter>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

In your code behind you will need to fill this parameter with the given data like so

```
SqlDataSource3.SelectParameters("TD").DefaultValue = 'your data
```